# Transformation of an equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How do you get from the left side to the right side in this equation?

$$\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} + 1  =\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2$$

Comment: they r not equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}(1+\sqrt{5})^2=\frac{1}{4}(6+2\sqrt{5})=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}= \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}+1$$